# Limpar markers e colocar os selecionados [javascript]

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Olá

Eu tou a criar um script para remover os markers e colocar so os markers especificos, mas so está a funcionar uma vez se eu depois tentar selecionar outro filtro os markers aparecem todos de volta e nao apagam e colocam os markers especificos, alguem me pode ajudar com o script?

Ao entrar na pagina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o filtro Masc selecionado: (so aparece o marker no porto)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o filtro Fem selecionado: (a marker do porto devia desaparecer)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O marker do Fem como ta selecionado o marker do porto devia selecionar, basicamente o que devia fazer era apagar os markers antigos novos e marcar os markers que o select indica... alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Codigo:

```js
function LoadJsonData() {

  var jsondata;

  $.ajax({ 
      url: './json/dados.json', 
      dataType: 'json', 
      async: false,
      success: function(json){ 
          jsondata = json;
      } 
  });

  return jsondata;
}

var map;
var markers = [];

    
function initMap() {

    var jsondata = LoadJsonData();

    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: { lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685 },
            zoom: 7,
            });
            
            for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
            var iconBase = './imagens/iconmapa2.png';
            var obj = jsondata[i];
    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: obj.title,
                id: obj.id,
                visible: true,
                icon: iconBase
            });

            markers.push(marker);
        }    
}

 function setMapOnAll(map) {
    var iconBase = './imagens/iconmapa2.png';
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].visible == true)
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markers[i].position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i].title,
                id: markers[i].id,
                visible: true,
                icon: iconBase
            });
        }
        else
        {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
  }

$(document).on("click", "#btnBuscar", function () {
    var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
    var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
    var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
    var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

    var arrayResultados = jsondata.filter(function (item) {
        var criteria = true;

        if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
        if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
        if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
        if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

        return criteria;

    });

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }    

    var iconBase = './imagens/iconmapa2.png';
 
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayResultados.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markers[arrayResultados[i].id-1].position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[arrayResultados[i].id-1].title,
        id: markers[arrayResultados[i].id-1].id,
        visible: true,
        icon: iconBase
    }); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="escolha">
          <form id="selectsfiltro">
            <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
            <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">0-17</option>
              <option value="2">18-25</option>
              <option value="3">26-35</option>
              <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
            </select>

            <br />
            <br />
            <h6>Sexo:</h6>
            <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
              <option></option>
              <option value="5">Masc</option>
              <option value="6">Fem</option>
            </select>

            <br />
            <br />
            <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
            <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
              <option></option>
              <option value="7">Sim</option>
              <option value="8">Não</option>
            </select>


            <br />
            <br />
            <h6>Localidade:</h6>
            <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
              <option></option>
              <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
              <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
              <option value="11">Bragança</option>
              <option value="12">Braga</option>
              <option value="13">Porto</option>
              <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
              <option value="15">Viseu</option>
              <option value="16">Guarda</option>
              <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
              <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
              <option value="19">Leiria</option>
              <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
              <option value="21">Santarém</option>
              <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
              <option value="23">Évora</option>
              <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
              <option value="25">Beja</option>
              <option value="26">Faro</option>
              <option value="27">Açores</option>
              <option value="28">Madeira</option>
            </select>
          </form>

          <br>

          <div class="botesdefiltrar">
            <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="map" class="googlemap"></div>
```

Comment: "basicamente o que devia fazer era apagar os markers antigos novos", são antigos ou novos? não podem ser a mesma coisa ao mesmo tempo, clarifique as coisas.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida basicamente o que eu preciso agora acho que é fazer um loop que faz com que quando voltarem a clicar no botão de filtrar iria apagar os markers antigos e por uns novos